# How to avoid, Tile Error: User memory exceed when trying to preform a Sentinel-2 SR cloud masking with s2cloudless

Tags: sentinel-2, cloud-cover, cloudmasking

I am trying to create a 2 cloudless composites of Sentinel-2 imagery over a region of interest that is pretty cloudy. I found an example script in GEE java script API that does a pretty aggressive cloud masking, however, when I tried to run it for a larger region I get this error:

> median Before: Tile error: User memory limit exceeded.

I tried increasing the `tileScale` parameter to 16, but it didn't solve my issue. Is there a way to make this work?

Here is the code I tried so far:

```
    // Sentinel-2 Level 1C data.  Bands B7, B8, B8A and B10 from this
    // dataset are needed as input to CDI and the cloud mask function.
    var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2');
    // Cloud probability dataset.  The probability band is used in
    // the cloud mask function.
    var s2c = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY');
    // Sentinel-2 surface reflectance data for the composite.
    var s2Sr = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR');


    // Dates over which to create a median composite.
    var start = ee.Date('2021-11-15');
    var end = ee.Date('2021-12-04');

    // S2 L1C for Cloud Displacement Index (CDI) bands.
    s2 = s2.filterBounds(StudyArea).filterDate(start, end)
    .select(['B7', 'B8', 'B8A', 'B10']);
    // S2Cloudless for the cloud probability band.
    s2c = s2c.filterDate(start, end).filterBounds(StudyArea);
    // S2 L2A for surface reflectance bands.
    s2Sr = s2Sr.filterDate(start, end).filterBounds(StudyArea)
    .select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5']);

    // Join two collections on their 'system:index' property.
    // The propertyName parameter is the name of the property
    // that references the joined image.
    function indexJoin(collectionA, collectionB, propertyName) {
        var joined = ee.ImageCollection(ee.Join.saveFirst(propertyName).apply({
        primary: collectionA,
        secondary: collectionB,
        condition: ee.Filter.equals({
        leftField: 'system:index',
        rightField: 'system:index'})
     }));
     // Merge the bands of the joined image.
     return joined.map(function(image) {
     return image.addBands(ee.Image(image.get(propertyName)));
     });
     }

     // Aggressively mask clouds and shadows.
     function maskImage(image) {
     // Compute the cloud displacement index from the L1C bands.
      var cdi = ee.Algorithms.Sentinel2.CDI(image);
      var s2c = image.select('probability');
      var cirrus = image.select('B10').multiply(0.0001);

     // Assume low-to-mid atmospheric clouds to be pixels where probability
     // is greater than 65%, and CDI is less than -0.5. For higher atmosphere
     // cirrus clouds, assume the cirrus band is greater than 0.01.
     // The final cloud mask is one or both of these conditions.
     var isCloud = s2c.gt(65).and(cdi.lt(-0.5)).or(cirrus.gt(0.01));

     // Reproject is required to perform spatial operations at 20m scale.
     // 20m scale is for speed, and assumes clouds don't require 10m precision.
     isCloud = isCloud.focal_min(3).focal_max(16);
     isCloud = isCloud.reproject({crs: cdi.projection(), scale: 20});

     // Project shadows from clouds we found in the last step. This assumes we're working in
     // a UTM projection.
     var shadowAzimuth = ee.Number(90)
     .subtract(ee.Number(image.get('MEAN_SOLAR_AZIMUTH_ANGLE')));

     // With the following reproject, the shadows are projected 5km.
     isCloud = isCloud.directionalDistanceTransform(shadowAzimuth, 50);
     isCloud = isCloud.reproject({crs: cdi.projection(), scale: 100});

     isCloud = isCloud.select('distance').mask();
     return image.select('B2', 'B3', 'B4').updateMask(isCloud.not());
     }

     // Join the cloud probability dataset to surface reflectance.
     var withCloudProbability = indexJoin(s2Sr, s2c, 'cloud_probability');
    // Join the L1C data to get the bands needed for CDI.
    var withS2L1C = indexJoin(withCloudProbability, s2, 'l1c');

    // Map the cloud masking function over the joined collection.
    var masked = ee.ImageCollection(withS2L1C.map(maskImage));

    // Take the median, specifying a tileScale to avoid memory errors.
    var median = masked.reduce(ee.Reducer.median(), 16);

    // Display the results.
    var viz = {bands: ['B4_median', 'B3_median', 'B2_median'], min: 0, max: 3000};
    Map.addLayer(median, viz, 'median');
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to integrate Temporal Subsetting as opposed to tweaking your `tileScale` any higher than 32. Divide your date range into smaller periods and create composites for those periods. Remerge these to get your final result.

I'll also mentioned that your discovered script is very resource-intensive, I'm sure there are simpler cloud masking algo's available in GEE that will require less memory.